# plot: group by multiple colmuns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

```
id  date        load          Instant  DayType  Month  Day  sort
0   2013-02-02  4667.341595   46       6        2      2    4667.341595
1   2013-02-02  4620.702889   47       6        2      2    4620.702889
2   2013-05-12  -4439.333624  3        0        5      12   4439.333624
3   2013-05-12  -4409.947044  4        0        5      12   4409.947044
4   2013-05-12  -4369.322473  5        0        5      12   4369.322473
```

Hi I have a function rmse:

```
def RMSE2(x):
    return(np.sqrt(np.mean(x**2)))
```

Load is our x I want to plot the return of rmse for each instant for each day type is mean I want to have in x instant and in y the return of my function AND 7 different plot (a plot for each daytype).

Comment: please revise the question, the last statement is ambiguous.

Comment: THANK YOU  I FOUND THE SOLUTION

Comment: if you found the solution please post the answer here in the spirit of stackoverflow, it might help others.

Comment: @suvy done the i posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
columns = np.unique(final.DayType)
b = []
for i in columns:
    daytype = final[final['DayType'] == i]
    a = daytype[['load']].groupby(daytype['Instant']).apply(RMSE2)
    b.append(a)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]
fig_size[0] = 8
fig_size[1] = 8
for i in range(9):
    x = range(48)  


    y = b[i]['load']
    plt.plot(x,y)

    plt.ylabel("Rmse")
    plt.xlabel("Day")

    plt.legend(range(9),loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=[0, 1],
           ncol=2, shadow=True, title="Legend", fancybox=True)




plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want ?

```
df.groupby('DayType')['load'].apply(lambda x:np.sqrt(np.mean(x**2)))
```

output :

```
DayType
0    4406.294544
6    4644.080789
Name: load, dtype: float64
```